Why is "I am me" not "I am I"?
In Latin, the case of a noun that follows a link verb is nominative, not accusative.
But in English, why do people say "I am me" not "I am I"? Is it different in English?

it's worth noting that traditional prescriptive grammars of English have often tried to assert that the Latin rule should also be followed in English, and claim that one ought to answer the question "who is it?" with "it is I" rather than the "it's me" that is universally preferred in the actual language as it is spoken

There is no rule of English grammar requiring a nominative form where a pronoun is complement of the verb "be". It's as simple as that.

@Tristan It’s also worth nothing that – as is the case in various other languages – this prescriptivist stance has rarely been taken beyond the third person. If neither the subject nor the predicate is a third-person pronoun, the nominative sounds utterly bizarre and was – as far as I know – never seriously prescribed. That is, even prescriptivists would say, “You are me” or “We are us”, rather than “*You are I” and “*We are we”.

[“Worth noting”, of course… not “worth nothing”!]

Yes, it's different in English. Noun phrases in English that aren't assigned a case end up accusative by default (or "objective" if you prefer): compare when they stand alone, like "who's there?" "me".

Obviously, English is not Latin. There is no reason to posit or prescribe any similarity that isn't there.
For the case assignment of copular verbs, you might expect nominative when you consider that the closest relatives have the nominative case in this position (consider German, for example, or Faeroese), or you might expect some oblique case or other, like in Russian or some other Indo-European languages.
But you wouldn't expect accusative, that's really weird. Accusatives can be promoted to subjects through passivisation, which is absolutely not possible with the example you gave. So what we have here is not accusative, but some other case that's homonymous with the accusative.
Consider French. You might hear "C'est moi", or "C'est toi" (the accusative, me or te do not work here), and it is this other case which appears in your example, "I am me".
As or your question, "why", it is possible that English developed this under influence from French. But I am not certain about that.

In Russian, it is nominative, like in Latin.

@Anixx, sometimes also instrumental: "Я был медьведем". But more important to note is that it's always a case which prohibits promotion to subject through passivisation

The ability for a constituent to be promoted to subject through passivisation is governed by syntactic properties and not necessarily linked to any specific case(s). English datives can be promoted to subjects in passive constructions, for example, but German ones can’t; and German accusatives that are due to prepositional control generally can’t either. I’m not aware of any language where copular constructions can be passivised, so it follows that their predicates also cannot be promoted to subjects through passivisation – but not because of the case they select.

And of course, there are other languages that select accusatives for such predicates: Irish and Danish do it mandatorily, Norwegian commonly, Swedish in some contexts; Spanish, Portuguese and Italian do it when the predicate is unstressed (only possible in the 3p); etc.
